# Is it possible to draw circuits through code?

Tags: circuit-design, programming, drawing

Is there a better way not by writing netlist files. something like:

```
Define Battery1 As a Battery
Define Resistor1 As a Resistor

Connect Battery1 First Terminal to Resistor1 Second Terminal
Connect Resistor1 First Terminal to Battery1 Second Terminal
```

EDIT:

I find the answers pretty helpful. It will be great if there is a way to simulate the circuit produced by the code.

Comment: FWIW, your example code looks like a netlist to me. It just defines a couple of parts (with presumably a library telling the tool how many terminals each one has) and then says which terminals are connected to each other. If you used it a bit you might even find it's easier to be able to name nodes and connect terminals to nodes rather than to other terminals.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify if you mean human-readable schematics? If so, I suspect that the answer is "no". Part of the joy of good schematics is that the draughts-person has laid the drawing out in a logic and legible format.

Comment: There is a wide gulf between "is it possible" and "is it useful", for many subjects.

Comment: @whatsisname It is easier to write code than to draw schematics by hand, as it will waste time thinking about the best way to draw it. Coding it is just straightforward.

Comment: You could also consider Spice, which is essentially a coded netlist and will plug straight into a simulator like LTSpice (free).

Comment: I think you might be looking at HDL. While they mostly describe digital circuits they are not technically limited to such (I think Verilog have some support for them). As noted by @ThePhoton what you have shown looks like a netlist, which is what they usually compile to.

Comment: The reason it takes time to think about the best way to draw it is that you have to have a good understanding of the circuit, and how to make its function clear to people looking at the drawing. None of that is stuff that computers are good at, so asking a computer to do it for you is asking for trouble.

Comment: If you're thinking you'll just use this description as input to the pcb layout tool, so it doesn't have to be used by a human reader, then what will you use as documentation for someone (you) troubleshooting the circuit after it's built, or modifying the design later. If you use schematic entry, you are essentially writing the documentation and using that as input to the layout tool. Now you know your layout will actually match the documentation.

Comment: Write your own.  I did this 43 years ago in Fortran.

Comment: Many schematic/capture programs provide a macro language that lets you do whatever you want.  EAGLE is strong in this area.

Answer (score 31):

If you are familiar with \$\LaTeX\$, you can use [circuitikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) to draw nice circuits by writing code.

[image]

[Example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/circuitikz/).
[More Examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/circuitikz/)

Comment: To add to this - as others have said drawing a good schematic requires some human intuition. However If you are drawing lots of similar circuits then using laTeX and circuitikz will allow you to construct a template layout and customise it with specifics.It is an approach I use in producing course materials.

Comment: The missing space between the number and the unit looks terrible.

Comment: @Loong You can always put space between numbers and units if you want. `\ ` or `\,`can add space in latex math environment

Comment: @Loong That's apparently a localization issue. As an American, it always seems bizarre to have random extra space between numbers and units.

Comment: @chrylis That's not a localisation issue, it's ISO 80000 specified and should be exclusively used.

Comment: The right way to handle formatting of SI units, in or out of the math environment, in LaTeX, is the siunitx package, which leaves a space.

Answer (score 16):

Check out SKiDL (https://github.com/xesscorp/skidl), this is along the lines you're thinking.

Edit (as req'd): SKiDL allows procedural description of all circuits (rather than just digital), instead of graphically entering your schematic. The netlist output can then be imported into layout software. It will also perform ERC checks, and is extensible. This means, for e.g., that you could write a filter once and then reuse it in different projects rather than drawing each time. Written in Python, with all the support that comes along with that.

Comment: Added a little more info.

Comment: Other Python schematic drawing options are [SchemDraw](https://cdelker.bitbucket.io/SchemDraw/) and [lcapy](http://lcapy.elec.canterbury.ac.nz/).

Answer (score 13):

Many programs can draw a schematic. None that I know of can draw a good schematic: One that emphasizes the most important information, and arranges the circuit in a clear and easy to understand way.

If you're just looking for a hardware description language (no graphical schematic output), VHDL and Verilog are widely used to define (digital) circuits to be implemented in ICs, and can also be used for board-level design.

Comment: Verilog-A can be used to describe and model/simulate analog circuits, as well, though I'm not aware of any non-commercial simulators.

Comment: I've designed some boards where it was easier to describe interconnections programmatically than with a schematic; I used a program to generate a netlist and then loaded it into PCB software.  If a schematic editor could import a netlist and show a ratsnest for connections that hadn't yet had "real" wires or explicit net labels drawn, that could be helpful in such cases, at least for the parts of the schematic where real wires made more sense than "air wires".

Comment: @Shamtam, I've used Veriolog A, but only as a simulation language. Are there systems that can synthesize a circuit from a Verilog A description?

Comment: @ThePhoton Not that I'm aware. I suppose my usage of the term "describe" could be misleading in that sense.

Comment: @Shamtam, I wouldn't worry about the word. It is a hardware **description** language after all. It just describes the function rather than the implementation.

Answer (score 9):

Your example looks a lot like [modelica](https://modelica.org/), an object oriented language for simulation based on creating blocks and connecting ports between the blocks.

An example using the electrical components library (from [maplesoft.com](https://www.maplesoft.com/documentation_center/online_manuals/modelica/Modelica_Electrical_Analog_Examples.html)),

```
encapsulated model ChuaCircuit "Chua's circuit, ns, V, A"
  import Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic;
  import Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Examples.Utilities;
  import Modelica.Icons;
  extends Icons.Example;

  Basic.Inductor L(L=18);
  Basic.Resistor Ro(R=12.5e-3);
  Basic.Conductor G(G=0.565);
  Basic.Capacitor C1(C=10, v(start=4));
  Basic.Capacitor C2(C=100);
  Utilities.NonlinearResistor Nr(
    Ga(min=-1) = -0.757576,
    Gb(min=-1) = -0.409091,
    Ve=1);
  Basic.Ground Gnd;
equation 
  connect(L.p, G.p);
  connect(G.n, Nr.p);
  connect(Nr.n, Gnd.p);
  connect(C1.p, G.n);
  connect(L.n, Ro.p);
  connect(G.p, C2.p);
  connect(C1.n, Gnd.p);
  connect(C2.n, Gnd.p);
  connect(Ro.n, Gnd.p);
end ChuaCircuit;
```

Although you can generate a schematic from the model, normally this is done in a GUI that annotates the components with position and orientation information.

Answer (score 4):

[Cirkuit](http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html) is an editor to convert a [simple text description](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html) to a circuit diagram. It provides a [set of M4 macros](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/) for electric symbols.

It can be used together with [circuitikz](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/) which was suggested by *nidhin*. 
circuitikz uses the more modern [pgf/TikZ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) graphic system. 
The stackexchange community has [very active users of cirkuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitikz), but there are [more solutions in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/electric-circuits-in-tex-latex-and-friends).

[image: Source: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/quick.png]

Picture from https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html.

Answer (score 3):

[PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery) is another library for TeX users. It can even do complicated mathematical calculation such as differential equations.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-circ}
\psset
{
    dipolestyle=zigzag,
    labelangle=0,
    labeloffset=-.9,
    intensitylabeloffset=-.4,
    tensionstyle=pm,
    tensionoffset=.9,
    tensionlabeloffset=.9,
    %tensioncolor=red,
    %tensionlabelcolor=blue,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=none](12,-12)
 \pstGeonode[PosAngle={135,90,45,0,-45,-90,-135,180,45}]
  (2,-2){A}
  (6,-2){B}
  (10,-2){C}
  (10,-6){D}
  (10,-10){E}
  (6,-10){F}
  (2,-10){G}
  (2,-6){H}
  (6,-6){I}
 %
 \resistor[intensitylabel=$i_1$,tensionlabel=$V_{HA}$](H)(A){$R_1$}
 \resistor[tensionlabel=$V_{AB}$](A)(B){$R_2$}
 \vdc[tensionlabel=$V_{BC}$](B)(C){$E_1$}
 \resistor[tensionlabel=$V_{CB}$](C)(D){$R_3$}
 %
 \resistor[intensitylabel=$i_2$,tensionlabel=$V_{HI}$](H)(I){$R_4$}
 \vdc[tensionlabel=$V_{ID}$](I)(D){$E_2$}
 %
 \resistor[intensitylabel=$i_3$,tensionlabel=$V_{HG}$](H)(G){$R_5$}
 \newSwitch[ison=true,tensionlabel=$V_{GF}$](G)(F){$S_2$}
 \wire(F)(E)
 \resistor[tensionlabel=$V_{DE}$,dipoleconvention=generator](E)(D){$R_6$}
 %
 \vdc[tensionlabel=$V_{FI}$,dipoleconvention=generator](I)(F){$E_3$}
 \newSwitch[intensitylabel=$i_4$,tensionlabel=$V_{BI}$,ison=false](B)(I){$S_1$} 
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes.You can use HDLs to describe your circuit through code.You can use verilator,Xilinx or any other softwares or you can use the https://www.edaplayground.com/ (which works online without having to install anything on your PC).

Answer (score 2):

See [`Schemdraw`](https://schemdraw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which allows you to draw circuits using Python.

```py
with schemdraw.Drawing():
    elm.Resistor().right().label('1Ω')
    elm.Capacitor().down().label('10μF')
    elm.Line().left()
    elm.SourceSin().up().label('10V')
```

[image]